# "Swift does not support static libraries when" After adding a Swift podfile

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods

I'm integrating swift in to an old Objective c project.
After adding "use_frameworks!" to my podfile, the projects compiles smoothly.
But when I try to add a Swift CocoaPods I'm getting

"Swift does not support static libraries when"'.

podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

xcodeproj 'ProjectDaily', 'Preprod' => :release, 'Test' => :release, 'Automation' => :release, 'Beta' => :release

#link_with 'ProjectDaily', 'ProjectDailyShare'

target :ProjectDaily do
```

//When adding this Swift cocoapods, or any ether pod writen in Swift, I get "Swift does not support static libraries when"

```
pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 2.4' // THIS 

    pod 'ProjectCommon', :path => 'Common/ProjectCommon'
    #pod 'Project-ios-sdk', :path => 'ProjectDaily/ProjectN/Project-ios-sdk'
    pod 'FormatterKit/TimeIntervalFormatter', '~> 1.4.3' # there is an issue with latest version
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.7.1'
    pod 'libextobjc', '~> 0.3'
    pod 'RSKImageCropper', '~>1.2.1'
    pod 'MGSwipeTableCell', '~>1.5.3' 
    pod 'libPhoneNumber-iOS', '~> 0.8' #Replaces ECPhoneNumberFormatter
    pod 'hpple'
    pod 'JTSImageViewController'
    pod 'TTTAttributedLabel'
    pod 'DTRichTextEditor'

    pod 'Reveal-iOS-SDK', :configurations => ['Debug']
    pod 'AFNetworkActivityLogger', :configurations => ['Debug']
    pod 'pop', '~> 1.0'
    pod 'FormatterKit'
    pod 'UINavigationBar+Addition'
    pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.1'
    pod 'Mixpanel', '2.9.3'
    pod 'Smartling.i18n', '~> 1.0'
    pod 'MTZImageFacePan', '0.2.0'
    pod 'CWStatusBarNotification', '~> 2.3.4'
end


target :ProjectDailyShare do
    pod 'ProjectCommon/Identity', :path => 'Common/ProjectCommon'
    pod 'UITextView+Placeholder', '~> 1.1'
    pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.7.1'
    pod 'ProjectCommon/SharedExtension', :path => 'Common/ProjectCommon'
    pod 'Smartling.i18n', '~> 1.0'
end

install! 'cocoapods',
         :deduplicate_targets => false

post_install do |add_app_extension_macro|
    add_app_extension_macro.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        if target.name.include?("Pods-ProjectDailyShare")
            puts "Adding 'AF_APP_EXTENSIONS=1 SHARE_EXTENSION=1' to 'GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS' in #{target.name}"
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['$(inherited)', 'AF_APP_EXTENSIONS=1 SHARE_EXTENSION=1']
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Way is this happening?

Comment: i am good with pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 2.1'

Comment: Its not about the Kingfisher version.. I tried ether Swift pods too, all the same /:

Comment: Check if the pod supports dynamic framework